# use db constraints to limit a foreign key to have only one boolean value false while others true

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-constraints

[image: when i run migrations i get an error could not create unique index "unique_is_performed_False" DETAIL: Key (is_performed)=(f) is duplicated.]i am having a model below

```
class MaintenancePersonnel(models.Model):
    performed_by=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    work_performed=models.ForeignKey(EquipmentMaintenanceSchedule,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comments=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    is_performed=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want for a given work performed to have only one field that has is_performed False

i have tried using condition but this seems to force only one model to have is_performed equal to false regardless of the work performed

```
class Meta:
        constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['work_performed','is_performed'], condition=models.Q(is_performed=False), name='unique_is_performed_False')
    ]
```

Comment: What is not working with this condition?

Comment: Currently its limiting is performed false to only one model instance. For example when i have work_performed  with id 1 equal to false I cant have is_performed false with instance of id 2 or 3.

Comment: Normally if `work_performed` is a field in the `UniqueConstraint` as is here the case, that should work. What will *not* work however is that two (or more) performers can have the same `work_performed` will have both `is_performed` set to `False`, that is what the constraint is saying.

Comment: So how should i set the `UniqueConstraint` so that regardless of other fields, the same work performed can not have `is_performed =False` more than once

Comment: can you give some examples about what *should* be allowed and what should *not* be allowed.

Comment: `performed_by=1, work_performed=1, is_performed=False. `.    Say I add another instance `performed_by=1, work_performed=2, is_performed=False. `.

Comment: `performed_by=1, work_performed=1, is_performed=False`.Say I add another instance `performed_by=5, work_performed=1, is_performed=False`THIS SHOULDN'T BE ALLOWED

Comment: I hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your UniqueConstraint field to just work_performed with the is_performed condition.

```
models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['work_performed'], condition=models.Q(is_performed=False), name='unique_is_performed_False')
```

This should limit your models to one work_performed where is_performed is false. It seems similar to the case provided in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/#condition)

Comment: still does not work

Comment: see I've added a snap of my db and still gives me an error `could not create unique index "unique_is_performed_False" DETAIL:  Key (is_performed)=(f) is duplicated.`

Comment: yeah it works bro. seemed like there is an issue when making migrations in a table.what i did is remove all `is_performed` false and make migrations and now it works as i want

Comment: @Dante that means your code already worked like you wanted... read [ask], if you were getting an error you should have mentioned it in your question.

Comment: I think mentioned about the error in a comment above. Sorry next time I'll add it in the question.